# Запрос в цикле Smarty

Tags: запрос, циклы, smarty

Использую Smarty, чтобы отделить HTML-код от PHP, возникла проблемка.

Когда код был вперемешку, я делал такую конструкцию:

```
$q_c = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `cart_id_products`, `cart_amount` FROM `cart` WHERE `cart_ip`='$my_ip'");
while($r_c = mysqli_fetch_array($q_c)) {
    $id_pro = $r_c['cart_id_products'];
    $amount_pro = $r_c['cart_amount'];

    $q = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id`='$id_pro'");
    $r = mysqli_fetch_array($q);

    $id_tov = $r['id'];
    $name = $r['name'];
    $image = $r['image'];
    $amount_product = $r['amount'];
    $link = $r['link'];
}
```

И затем выводил корзину. Сейчас же при использовании смарти не получается сделать такую штуку. Пробовал конечно через двойной `foreach`:

```
{foreach from=$cart item=cart_p}
    {foreach from=$products item=product}
    //Тот же вывод корзины
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

где `$cart` это старый `$q_c`, а `$products` это `$q`. Но не работает.

Подскажите, как сделать?

Comment: не совсем ясно. что у вас находится внутри переменных `$cart` и `$products`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку формат данных в шаблоне не понятен, предложу следующее решение. Во-первых, вызов SQL запроса в цикле обычно не используется и ни к чему хорошему не приводит. Во-вторых, передача параметров в запрос путем простой подстановки в тело sql чревата инъекциями кода, но этот момент мы оставим за рамками ответа.

Итак, сначала выберите все данные одним запросом. Судя по всему связь там у вас один к одному.

```
$q = mysqli_query($db, "
          SELECT `cart_id_products`, `cart_amount` , p.*
          FROM `cart`  AS c
          INNER JOIN `products` AS p ON (p.id = c.cart_id_products)
          WHERE `cart_ip`='$my_ip'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $data[] = $row;
}
$smarty->assign('cart', $data);
```

тогда в шаблоне для вывода простой цикл

```
 {foreach $cart as $c}
      {$c.cart_amout}, {$c.name}
 {/foreach}
```

Обычно же, данные просто подготавливают удобным способом (применительно данного вопроса - группируют вручную результаты выборки после запроса). И для примера

```
$data = [
          'row1' => ['title' => "Строка 1", 'items' => [1,2,3]], 
          'row2' => ['title' => "Строка 2", 'items' => [10,9,8]]
        ];
```

выводят как-то так

```
{foreach $data as $row}
    Строка - {$row.title}
    {foreach $row.items as $item}
        Элемент {$item}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Я примерно понял как надо, но как тогда вывести такой массив $data, ведь я получаю данные из бд циклом, мне получается надо части $data = [ и ]; за цикл вынести, а внутренности собирать непосредственно в самом цикле, что РНР обрабатывать не будет.

Comment: @AidenProgrammer я вам про то и говорю, вроде, что циклом данным из БД таскать не надо. всю предварительную обработку данных вы должны провести в пхп коде, в шаблон уже должны быть переданы удобные для использования данные  и тем более там не должно быть никаких запросов к БД

Comment: Но если не цикл, тогда только одна строка из бд получаться будет, так как точное количество неизвестно данных, ведь покупатель может заказать и один товар и десять

Comment: @AidenProgrammer вы можете написать один запрос в `LEFT/INNER JOIN`  двух таблиц, чтобы извлечь все данные, потом сгрупипровать их нужным образом?

Comment: О, INNER JOIN решил проблему, спасибо большое!

Comment: @AidenProgrammer это причем было написано в коде ответа :)